# How to configure Jade with sailsjs and angularjs to serve client-side templates

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, sails.js, pug

How do I configure sailjs to render angular templates served by angular controllers? (i.e., these are templates served from the `assets` directory, not the `view` directory where Jade server-side templates normally reside.)

I succeed at rendering `views/layout.jade` at '/' by setting my `views` engine to Jade and route to

```
module.exports.routes={
  '/': {
    view: 'layout'
  }
}
```

I put my angular templates in `assets/templates` but Express cannot find them. My `ui-router` config below tries to serve `helloWorld.html` but the file is not found (because it is actually still helloWorld.jade);

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      resolve: {},
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: '/views/helloWorld.html',
      controller: 'HelloWorldCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'HelloWorld'
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you added angular and your application to pipeline.js?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, that part is all working.